# How would I change this script to go by TimeZone eg: Europe/London as the results are different for each TZ

Tags: javascript, node.js

How would I change this script [below] to go by TimeZone `eg: Europe/London` as the results are different for each TZ.

```js
new Date(res.data.statuses[1]['services_platforms'][0].updated).toLocaleString()
```

Outputs: `2020-09-30T23:09:50` (eg)

The script is ran on US Based server so by default the `.toLocaleString()` defaults to `America/Detroit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the documentation:
[MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Basically, you can provide up to two optional arguments. The first one is for `locales`, for example `.toLocaleString('en-GB')`. Second is for options, where you can specify timezone (`.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC' })`), check the doc link above. That is at least where I found the answer when I was dealing with the same issue. Hope it was what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into to this matter later today when I have some time to spare and get back to you :)